# Avoid singleton in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express, sails.js, passport.js

I've read several times that a singleton should be avoided as much as possible. By singleton I mean this kind of code

```
exports = module.exports = new Passport();
```

This code is from the Node.js module PassportJS. It allows us to use passport and add some var that will be shared inside our entire code.

So as you can see we can make this code:
https://github.com/ragulka/sails-starter-app/blob/master/api/controllers/SessionController.js
(This is just an example, I do too and I blame no one).
Note that he is taking passport at the top of the file with require and then using one of the strategies that have been added previously in the code. Obviously it's convenient but is it the best way to do this?

Is there no way to pass passport variable inside controllers from previous code?

Let me know if something is not clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a use case for having multiple instances of the Passport object?

Comment: `exports = module.exports = ...` is redundant. `module.exports === exports`; they're mapped to the same location.

Comment: Also, singletons are fine. Not sure where you heard that. Singletons are just a design pattern; like any design pattern, they aren't inherently *good* or *bad*, they just *are*. If they make sense for an application then they should be used.

Comment: Dan D, no use case it was just for example about singleton.

Qix, I heard that on stackoverflow ^^.

Thanks you for explanations :).

Answer (score 4):

There are cases like this, a passport instance, an express app instance, a mongodb connection pool, a logger instance, etc, where the most common case is a single instance per node process. In these situations, a singleton can be convenient and keep code concise, provided the module also provides an easy way to access and call the constructor for those minority times you want more than one instance (like if your app wants to 2 distinct pools of connections to 2 distinct mongodb databases, or 2 different log streams, for example).

This can sometimes be inconvenient for testing, mocking, stubbing, etc, though.

> Is there no way to pass passport var inside controllers from previous code ?

Yes, there is. When you do `var passport = require("passport");` you will always get back the exact same singleton instance, including all it's internal state as configured by other code in your application. This is due to the caching that happens in the node `require` call. What takes extra code is if you want to create a new distinct `Passport` instance, in which case you need to call the constructor yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which is very clear but just a precision about my part you highlighted.

I wanted to mean, is there a way to do properly this kind of code ?

`// before controller
`var passport = require('passport');`
`// do some stuff`

`// inside controller`
`auth: function(req, res, next){`
`    var passport = req.app.passport;`
`// ...`

I don't know if you see what I mean :)

Comment: Yes, you **can** share objects via the `req`, `res`, and `app` objects in a connect/express application. In this specific case, it's just another approach that accomplishes the same thing as having multiple files require passport and manipulate it. Not sure exactly what you are asking but always a specific question with a real piece of working code is easier to discuss than general/vague/codeless questions.